# Change CSS on span tag in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am trying to change the CSS for a `span` tag using C# but I am unable to do so. I have tried to give it a type of `HTMLGenericControl` but cannot get the `CssClass` tag to popup in IntelliSense.

```html
<span id="collegeSpan" runat="server" class="college">other code here</span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
collegeSpan.Attributes["class"] = "foo";
```

Comment: that works but it only picks up one of the styles. i figured it out by entering each style manaully by doing <code>collegeSpan.Style.Add("padding", "5px");</code> Thanks for the help

Comment: I presume that multiple CSS class names can also be specified, e.g., `= "foo bar fiz";`?

Answer (score 5):

Because a late answer is better then no answer at all, for the record:
If you're able to alter the HTML/ASCX; use the asp:Label-control instead of a span. Label-controls are rendered to the page as a span, but it has some advantages, including the possibility to alter the "CssClass"-property :-)

Comment: @DavidRR Please don't edit answers if your edits are not of a substantive nature. It is not up to you to determine whether or not I use smileys, or how I exactly choose to formulate my answer.